# how to download file in php

Tags: php, download

I want to download image file in php.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["file"])){

    $filepath = BASE_URL.'assets/uploads/save_template_images/template1_221594899972.png';

    // Process download
    if(file_exists($filepath)) {
        echo $filepath;
        exit;
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
        flush(); // Flush system output buffer
        readfile($filepath);
        die();
    } else {
        echo $filepath;
        exit;
        http_response_code(404);
        die();
    }
} 

?>
```

In my index page, I have an anchor tag and if click on anchor tag then above code run. I am not showing anchor tag because, I put the **$filepath** static value in above code. When I run above code then it goes on else condition. I think, full path of project is not taking by above code. If I put image in same folder then it downloads.

Comment: what is value of contant in BASE_URL ? it should https://www.domainname.com/assets/uploads/save_template_images/template1_221594899972.png

Comment: It is http://localhost/assets/uploads/save_template_images/

Comment: http://localhost/assets/uploads/save_template_images/template1_221594899972.png

Comment: echo your  $filepath and ensure that path is correct and image is there inside folder

Comment: Learn the difference between an HTTP URL, and a file system path.

Comment: @vinod can you please give me an upvote for my answer? I am also a new contributor and it will help me alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure `allow_url_fopen` setting in `php.ini` file is turned on. After that Use this code to download your file:

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-5.jpg';
    $file = './files/'.basename($url);
    file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

For successful download, files directory must be exists. But I think it would be inefficient to add directory existence check as I think you already know where to save the file you are downloading.

Comment: Sorry for up vote. Because also I am new contributor. I tried but it gives message........Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Oh. Still thanks for your effort **:)  Happy Coding**.